# Usability testing with users with ASD?

Tags: interface, user-experience, heuristics, usability-testing, cognitive-complexity

Has anyone ever conducted usability testing with users with ASD?

I need to test an existing website to make sure it is suitable for neurodivergent users as well. I would need to ask testers to perform a list of tasks on a targeted website and I've been wondering whether I should consider a specific approach to make sure the testers don't get annoyed or frustrated and the test is successful.

I would appreciate if you could give me any piece of advice.Thank you.